# How to customising subclass implementation at runtime in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass

MyTextField is a `UITextField` subclass to have extra margin in textfield.

```
@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@property (nonatomic, assign) bool enableMargin;
- (instancetype) initWithMarginEnable:(BOOL)enable;
@end

@implementation MyTextField
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    if(self.enableMargin) return;

    return CGRectInset(bounds, 32.5f, 0);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

- (instancetype) initWithMarginEnable:(BOOL)enable {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.enableMargin = enable;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

#### This is working fine !

```
MyTextField *txt = [[MyTextField alloc] init];
```

but at some point in my app, I require to not have any margin, however, to keep continuity and for some good reason I still have to use `MyTextField` throughout the app.

#### This doesn't help !

```
MyTextField *txt = [[MyTextField alloc] initWithMarginEnable:YES];
```

But in my personal investigation I realized that `textRectForBounds:` method will always call before `MyTextField`'s get `init`.

How do I make it (or check it) that I don't want margin or not? I've tried with a custom `init` method but it still calls `textRectForBounds:`.

And yes, my app will supports iOS7 > so any advice/suggestion/answer should be based on this condition ONLY :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to call `setNeedsDisplay` after setting the `enableMargin` property. You don't need to make a separate `init`, I would do it as:

```
 @implementation MyTextField

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {

    if(self.enableMargin) return CGRectInset(bounds, 0, 0);;

    return CGRectInset(bounds, 32.5f, 0);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

-(void)setEnableMargin:(bool)enableMargin {
    _enableMargin = enableMargin;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

To use it, you would have to call:

```
 MyTextField *myText = [[MyTextField alloc] init];
 myText.frame = // whatever the frame will be
 myText.enableMargin = YES;
```

Comment: Oh yes, I was thinking of that, I would accept your answer soon. Thanks :)